# Change UIImageView height while scaling down to specific width

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, height

I have a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView.

What I am trying to achieve is to have a flexible height for the UIIMageView depending on the image that is loaded in while keeping the width of the UIImageView the same.

I also don't want the UIImageView to scale from the centre, but rather from the top most point.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ashey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, adjusting the height of a UIView (or any of its subclasses) will adjust the height from the origin.y coordinate downwards. It doesn't span from the center.

Do you know the sizes of your image beforehand? If the images appear in the same order each time, you can just supply the sizes in an array.

If you do not know the sizes, or the order of the images, you can use the size property on the UIImage you are putting in your UIImageView. This will return to you a CGSize, of which you can take the height. You will also need to update the contentSize of the UIScrollView.